# Submit form data to email folder

Tags: php, forms, email, email-validation

I am familiar with submitting a form and formatting it to an email address with PHP, but I have a client saying that with their last organization they had form submission set so incoming emails were categorized to particular folders.  I am not familiar with this functionality.

I did a Google search ad nothing applicable came up, so I turned to StackOverflow.

I have a simple script that I use for most client forms:

```
$redirectTo = "http://www.somedomain.com";
$to = "person@email.com";
$from = "Contact Form";
$subject = "Contact Form Submission";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$message = "";
$formFields = array_keys($_POST);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($formFields); $i++)
{
    $theField = strip_tags($formFields[$i]);
    $theValue = strip_tags($_POST[$theField]);
    $message .= $theField;
    $message .= " = ";
    $message .= $theValue;
    $message .= "\n";
}
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($success)
{
    header("Location: " . $redirectTo);
}
else
{
    echo "An error occurred when sending the email.";
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: "Rules" for sorting emails are done within the email client (Outlook, Gmail, etc)

Comment: or a mail server like exchange, but you can set custom headers to make it easier for that client\server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possibile. It's all handled client-side by using filters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Now I can tell the client no with confidence, and I will just have certain forms send to certain email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that have to be set in an email client program?  *(i.e. Google Mail, Outlook, etc.)*

Comment: That's what I thought.  Im not here to set up their infrastructure, just to get the incoming email to channel appropriately.  Their old developer must have set up their clients or something.